# how to plot xy coordinates for unique row values and trace line according to time?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

say i have:

```
df ={'animal' : [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3],
     'x':[76.551, 76.529, 76.336,76.249,  76.077, 77, 77.02, 77.23, 77.733],
     'y': [151.933, 151.945, 151.970, 152.004, 152.027, 118.369, 118.615, 118.935, 119.115],
    'time': [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 3,2,5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

how would i plot the xy coordinates for each unique animal? i was trying stuff with .groupby and .unique (not working). i'm able to plot the scatter plot with:

```
plt.scatter(df[['x']], df[['y']])
```

but how can i iterate over each unique animal and plot their coordinates (in different colours), then how to draw a line between points according to sequential time points?

Comment: are you asking how to do this by filtering & sorting the data yourself to how to declaratively specify the plot?

Comment: are you open to use seaborn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

cmap = cm.get_cmap('rainbow')
colors = cmap(np.linspace(0.15, 0.85, df['animal'].nunique()))
color_map = dict(zip(df['animal'].unique(), colors))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for animal, subdf in df.sort_values('time').groupby('animal'):
    ax.plot(subdf['x'], subdf['y'], marker='o', label=animal, c=color_map[animal])
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you! do you know how to plot the lines according to time (ex, for the 3rd line in orange, it should go from starting point to (77.230, 118.935) back to (77.02, 118.615)? or i guess there's a sort/order function that can be applied on time after grouping by animal in python eh

Comment: so i can `groupby('animal')` and `sort_values('time')` with `df.groupby('animal').apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('time'))` but it doesn't preserve the proper dataframe structure to plot after (adds new index level for animal). in R we can pass commands through pipe %>% in order to modify a dataframe sequentially.. is there a way to do the same here (groupby animals then sort the time to then plot)?

Comment: Why *starting point to (77.230, 118.935)* fir 3rd line? It should be (77.000, 118.369), no?

Comment: Prefer something like `df.sort_values('time').groupby('animal')`. Because you sort values one time instead of N x number of animals.

Comment: yes, my mistake, i didn't order it and just looked at the df and misread the time order. sorry

Comment: hi, sorry, i'm getting the error `'Series' object cannot be interpreted as an integer` after `df.sort_values('time').groupby('animal')`

Comment: Did you try with your toy example? It works fine for me. I updated my code.